# TypeError: messages.greetings is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I am trying to import a TypeScript module which is compiled using Webpack, but am getting the following error,

```
TypeError: messages.sayHello is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gaurangdave/workspace/experiments/tmp/ts_modules/main.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Below is the TypeScript,

```
const sayHello = name => {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
};

export default { sayHello };
```

Below is the Webpack Config,

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
     mode: 'none',
     entry: {
          greetings: './greetings.ts',
     },
     target: 'node',
     resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
     },
     optimization: {
          minimize: false
     },
     output: {
          // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
          path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
          filename: '[name].js'
     },
     module: {
          rules: [{
               test: /\.ts$/,
               loader: 'ts-loader'
          }]
     },
     plugins: []
}
```

Am kind of blocked on this, can someone please throw some light?

Thanks
Gaurang

Edit:

I am calling the sayHello function as follows,

```
const greetings = require('./dist/greetings');

greetings.sayHello();
```

Comment: Can you double check the code you've posted? There is no 'messages' object or a greetings function in it.

Comment: Hi @AksharPatel thanks for pointing it out, I had copied old version of the code, but I still see the issue when I call the sayHello function. I think I have a workaround by using typescript compiler directly, but still want to figure out what am I missing here.